# Exporting extra reducers from redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I made a todo list a while ago as a way to practice react and redux. Now I'm trying to rewrite it with redux toolkit and having some trouble with the action creators.

Here is the old actions creator:

```
export const changeDescription = (event) => ({
    type: 'DESCRIPTION_CHANGED',
    payload: event.target.value })

export const search = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const description = getState().todo.description
        const search = description ? `&description__regex=/${description}/` : ''
        axios.get(`${URL}?sort=-createdAt${search}`)
            .then(resp => dispatch({ type: 'TODO_SEARCHED', payload: resp.data }))
    } }

export const add = (description) => {
    return dispatch => {
        axios.post(URL, { description })
            .then(() => dispatch(clear()))
            .then(() => dispatch(search()))
    } }

export const markAsDone = (todo) => {
    return dispatch => {
        axios.put(`${URL}/${todo._id}`, { ...todo, done: true })
            .then(() => dispatch(search()))
    } }

export const markAsPending = (todo) => {
    return dispatch => {
        axios.put(`${URL}/${todo._id}`, { ...todo, done: false })
            .then(() => dispatch(search()))
    } }

export const remove = (todo) => {
    return dispatch => {
        axios.delete(`${URL}/${todo._id}`)
        .then(() => dispatch(search()))
    } }

export const clear = () => {
    return [{ type: 'TODO_CLEAR' }, search()] }
```

Now this is the one that I'm working on, I'm trying to replicate the actions of the old one but using redux toolkit:

```
export const fetchTodos = createAsyncThunk('fetchTodos', async (thunkAPI) => {
    const description = thunkAPI.getState().todo.description
    const search = description ? `&description__regex=/${description}/` : ''
    const response = await axios.get(`${URL}?sort=-createdAt${search}`)
    return response.data
})

export const addTodos = createAsyncThunk('fetchTodos', async (thunkAPI) => {
    const description =  thunkAPI.getState().todo.description
    const response = await axios.post(URL, {description})
    return response.data
})

export const todoReducer = createSlice({
    name: 'counter',
    initialState: {
        description: '',
        list: []
    },
    reducers: {
        descriptionChanged(state, action) {
            return {...state, dedescription: action.payload}
        },
        descriptionCleared(state, action) {
            return {...state, dedescription: ''}
        },

    },
    extraReducers: builder => {
        builder
         .addCase(fetchTodos.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
             const todo = action.payload
             return {...state, list: action.payload}
         })
         .addCase(addTodos.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            let newList = state.list
            newList.push(action.payload)
            return {...state, list: newList}
        })
    }
})
```

The thing is, I can't find anywhere how to export my extra reducers so I can use them. Haven't found anything in the [docs](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux). Can someone help?

Comment: Just export `todoReducer.reducer`.  The slice includes the `reducers` and the `extraRedcuers`.

Comment: You have a typo `dedescription` but also it seems like your actions should only be updating a single todo in the list, no?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### extraReducers

Calling `createSlice` creates a slice object with properties `reducers` and `actions` based on your arguments.  The difference between `reducers` and `extraReducers` is that only the `reducers` property generates matching action creators.  But both will add the necessary functionality to the reducer.

You have correctly included your thunk reducers in the `extraReducers` property because you don't need to generate action creators for these, since you'll use your thunk action creator.

You can just export `todoReducer.reducer` (personaly I would call it `todoSlice`). The reducer function that is created includes both the reducers and the extra reducers.

### Edit: Actions vs. Reducers

It seems that you are confused by some of the terminology here.  The slice object created by `createSlice` (your `todoReducer` variable) is an object which contains both a reducer and actions.

The **reducer** is a single function which takes the previous state and an action and returns the next state.  The only place in your app when you use the reducer is to create the store (by calling `createStore` or `configureStore`).

An **action** in redux are the things that you `dispatch`.  You will use these in your components.  In your code there are four action creator functions: two which you created with `createAsyncThunk` and two which were created by `createSlice`.  Those two will be in the actions object `todoReducer.actions`.

#### Exporting Individually

You can `export` each of your action creators individually and import them like:

```
import {fetchTodos, descriptionChanged} from "./path/file";
```

Your `fetchTodos` and `addTodos` are already exported.  The other two you can destructure and export like this:

```
export const {descriptionChanged, descriptionCleared} = todoReducer.actions;
```

You would call them in your components like:

```
dispatch(fetchTodos())
```

#### Exporting Together

You might instead choose to export a single object with all of your actions.  In order to do that you would combine your thunks with the slice action creators.

```
export const todoActions = {
  ...todoReducer.actions,
  fetchTodos,
  addTodos
}
```

You would import like this:

```
import {todoActions} from "./path/file";
```

And call like this:

```
dispatch(todoActions.fetchTodos())
```

Comment: I'm trying to call them but it gives me an error saying it's not a function. I'm calling it like this: dispatch(todoReducer.fetchTodos())

Comment: You are confused on the terminology.  `fetchTodos` is an **action** not a **reducer**.   You need to `import {fetchTodos} from './file'` and call `dispatch(fetchTodos())`;

Comment: your answer is pretty good, especially you explained the termiology of "reducer" and "actions", but, I believe same as the author asked, what I want to achieve is, a simple thing like:
export const TodoActions = todoReducer.AllActions
which includes both the actions from createSlice and the async ones (created out of createSlice).
The reason for this is, so that I don't need to manually add the action that was newly developed, since it's already included into "extraReducers", so the reducer actually knows about it.

Comment: Hi scotty, your async thunk actions cannot be accessed from the slice object.  If you want to export all of your actions together, you could do something like this (untested) `export const TodoActions = { ...todoReducer.actions, fetchTodos, addTodos }`.

Answer (score 0):

The key is on creating a root Reducer and a root Action, same you could configure store with the rootReducer.

```html
const rootReducer = combineSlices({ 
    todoReducer: todoReducer.reducer,
    exampleReducer: exampleReducer.reducer
});

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer
})

export const rootActions = {
  ...todoReducer.actions,
  ...exampleReducer.actions
}

export default rootReducer;
```

And use store importing the RootActions:

```
import { rootActions } from 'reducer';
```

And Dispatch with the rootActions:

```
 dispatch(rootActions.descriptionChanged());
```